# System Audio is picked up on microphone when using headphones (discord, skype, macOS), how do I turn this off?

Tags: audio, headphones, settings, microphone

Specs: macOS Sierra 10.12.5, JBL in-ear headphones with microphone

Ever since I got my new headphones, people on Discord and Skype could listen to me watching videos and listening to music, which is pretty annoying. At first I thought this was the fault of those applications, but when checking the input settings of Sound Preferences I saw that macOS was picking up on this as well.

I have tried changing settings in the Audio/Midi configuration but my headphones don't show up as a new device but changes the settings of my built-in microphone (from internal microphone to external microphone), so I can't select the mac's original built-in microphone.

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Pictures for reference:

**Before plugging in my headphones:**

[image: before plugging in my headphones]

**After plugging in my headphones:**

[image: after plugging in my headphones]